# css hover : only works on one image but no multiple how define function

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a simple hover effect. I used the template from the website corelangs.com

It totally works but only when I have only 1 hover effect in the document.

I.e :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.urlImg { width: 300px; height:211px; display:block; background-image: url('images/001.jpg'); } .urlImg:hover { background-image: url('images/001over.jpg'); } </style>
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.corelangs.com" class="urlImg" title="Corelangs link">
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

However, If I want to implement two different hovers. ( basically I want to do a thumbnail overview with say 12 projects and when clicking on the thumbnails they hover and become a different image. It totally fails...

In this example I added 2 second hover

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.urlImg { width: 300px; height:211px; display:block; background-image: url('images/001.jpg'); } .urlImg:hover { background-image: url('images/001over.jpg'); }

.urlImg2 { width: 300px; height:211px; display:block; background-image: url('images/002.jpg'); } .urlImg:hover { background-image: url('images/002over.jpg'); }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<a href="http://www.corelangs.com" class="urlImg" title="Corelangs link"></a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.corelangs.com" class="urlImg2" title="Corelangs link"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

doesnt work...any ideas what to change ?

Comment: Do you want to have an effect occur when a mouse "hovers" over a `div` or are you trying to make the image *hover*, appearing to float over the rest of the page?

Comment: There is `urlImg:hover` 2 times, but there is no  `urlImg2:hover`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a minor copy-paste error as you are repeating `.urlImg:hover` twice instead of using `.urlImg2:hover` :

```
.urlImg { /*omitted for brevity */ } 
.urlImg:hover { background-image: url('images/001over.jpg'); }

.urlImg2 { /* omitted for brevity */ } 
.urlImg2:hover { background-image: url('images/002over.jpg'); }
```

Comment: that means I can do everything I want now ;)